# Deriving Affinity from Individual Terms in Autodock Vina Scoring Output

Tags: bioinformatics

I am currently working with the output from Autodock Vina using the --score_only argument and I'm having some difficulty understanding how to combine the different score terms (gauss 1, gauss 2, repulsion, hydrophobic, Hydrogen) to calculate the Affinity value.

According to the related publication (DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334), there's a set of weights for these terms, but the way to use these weights to obtain the Affinity is unclear to me. It doesn't appear to be a straightforward linear combination.

Can someone help me to find the right formula to recover the Affinity from these terms?

Here's an example of the output I'm working with:

```
Reading input ... done.
Setting up the scoring function ... done.
Affinity: -6.13476 (kcal/mol)
Intermolecular contributions to the terms, before weighting:
    gauss 1     : 79.40942
    gauss 2     : 1285.97614
    repulsion   : 2.61957
    hydrophobic : 21.88511
    Hydrogen    : 4.41061
```

As per the associated paper (DOI 10.1002/jcc.21334), there are specified weights for these score terms, but I'm struggling to discern how these weights are applied to yield the Affinity value. I've attempted a direct linear combination using these weights:

```
  --weight_gauss1 arg (=-0.035579)
  --weight_gauss2 arg (=-0.005156)
  --weight_repulsion arg (=0.84024500000000002)
  --weight_hydrophobic arg (=-0.035069000000000003)
  --weight_hydrogen arg (=-0.58743900000000004)
```

Furthermore, I've also considered the extra weight for rotatable bonds --weight_rot arg (=0.058459999999999998), given the example output I'm examining includes 13 active torsions.

Despite this, I haven't managed to successfully reconcile these figures to get the Affinity value.